# Bot causes double post in claimer.py

Tags: python

Well on my bot I keep using my claim command but it keeps making the bot double post two of the messages in the def claimer. This is the code:

```
   def claimer(user, name, room):
     if user.lower() == name.lower():
       room.message("Pfft. You can't catch yourself.")
     elif name.lower() not in room.usernames:
       room.message("You can't capture %s they are not here." % name.title())
     else:
       if not user in claim.claimDB:
         claim.claimDB[user] = []
       num = len(claim.claimDB[user])
       if claim.limit(num) == True:
         room.message("You have reached your limit on captures %s. You must release some people in order to catch %s" % (user.title(), name.title()))
       else:
         for a, b in claim.claimDB.items():
           if name.lower() in b:
             room.message("%s has already been caught by %s." % (name.title(), a.title())) 
           else:
             escapechance = random.choice([True,True,True,False])
             if escapechance == True:
               claim.claimDB[user] = claim.claimDB[user]+[name]
               room.message("//Pokeball wiggles three times before stopping// You have successfully captured %s! \o/" % name.title()) <----this message.
             else:
                room.message("Failed to capture them")<----- this one too at the same time.
```

The for a, b in claim.claimDB.items(): if name.lower() in b: is suppose to prevent the same name from being in the b in claim.claimDB.items() but instead causes those two messages to pop up and places the same name in the file again.

Comment: Your line that appends `name` (which should use `list.append()`) appends `name`, not `name.lower()`. `'foo'` isn't in `['Foo']`.

Comment: I'm a little confused by that. What line do you mean?

Comment: `claim.claimDB[user] = claim.claimDB[user]+[name]`

Comment: Oh so instead of +[name] i should use .append(name.lower()) or would I use +[name.lower()]?

Comment: The first one is best. Either that or change `if name.lower() in b:` to just `if name in b:`.

Comment: Okay now it is making the bot post the message under the +[name.lower()] and the else: room.message too.

Comment: Its still double posting those messages still